# extract string between two symbols in a one-line string

Tags: awk, sed

I have a one-line that contains multiple url's that I want to extract and print as new-lines. As shown in the example I want to extract the part between `{"url` and `"}` and print as a new line. Tried something like this:

```
sed -n 's/.*\{"url\(.*\)"}.*/\1/p'
```

IN

```
"crams":{"tumor":{"url:rvrvwedre"}}fawirnfaiwrunfiawun"crams":{"tumor":{"url:rvrvwdwEDerare"}}nowiaunrvwiorunwaeiou"crams":{"tumor":{"url:rvrverSQWSare"}}ieurnveiarunviearuv"crams":{"tumor":{"url:rvrveraSQWSQre"}}
```

OUT

```
url:rvrvwedre
url:rvrvwdwEDerare
url:rvrverSQWSare
url:rvrveraSQWSQre
```

Comment: If this is part of JSON, please post valid JSON.

Comment: sorry, yes it is. Got it to work in R. so closing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.[^{]*.[^{]*[^:]*\(url[^"]*\)[^}]*../\1\n/g' input_file
url:rvrvwedre
url:rvrvwdwEDerare
url:rvrverSQWSare
url:rvrveraSQWSQre
```

Comment: Hi, my real data was a bit different causing your solution to not work. I have updated with a more realistic example.

Comment: @user2300940 Please check edit

Answer (score 2):

If you have mutilated JSON and therefore using proper JSON parser is not option I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
"crams":{"tumor":{"url:rvrvwedre"}}fawirnfaiwrunfiawun"crams":{"tumor":{"url:rvrvwdwEDerare"}}nowiaunrvwiorunwaeiou"crams":{"tumor":{"url:rvrverSQWSare"}}ieurnveiarunviearuv"crams":{"tumor":{"url:rvrveraSQWSQre"}}
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="url:[^\x22]*"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){print $i}}' file.txt
```

output

```
url:rvrvwedre
url:rvrvwdwEDerare
url:rvrverSQWSare
url:rvrveraSQWSQre
```

Explanation: I use `FPAT` (Field PATtern) to inform AWK that field is `url:` followed by 0 or more not-`"` (I used `\x22` to get `"` without ending string, 22(hex) is `"` in ASCII), then `for` each field I `print` it.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

If you are allowed to use `GNU grep` then you might elect to do

```
grep -o 'url:[^"]*' file.txt
```

Explanation: `-o` means print only what was matched.

*(tested in grep (GNU grep) 3.4)*

Comment: the grep solution is nice and succinct.